# Safari extension messaging

Tags: javascript, safari, safari-extension

I have been working on a Safari extension and have hit a wall. I cannot figure out how to send multiple lines of data from global to the inject.
I have been searching for a while on this site and others and only have found bits and pieces, but when combined fail.

Heres what I need to get out of Global
    `safari.extension.secureSettings.username;`
    `safari.extension.secureSettings.password;`
I've tried puting them into global variables but the inject doesn't see those.

inject code

```
document.getElementById('local_login').style.display='';
document.getElementById('local_login_link').style.display = 'none';
document.loginForm.username.value = /*Safari Secure Settings Username*/
document.loginForm.password.value = /*Safari Secure Settings Password*/
document.getElementById('localsubmit').click();
```

I tried the code from the Apple documentation but it wouldn't run any of the inject code.

**Edit**
Here is what I have so far. I'm just not sure why it isn't receiving, or sending.

Global.html

```
function sendCred() {
    myUsername = safari.extension.secureSettings.username;
    myPassword = safari.extension.secureSettings.password;
    var arrayNSA = [myUsername, myPassword];
    safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage("nsaArray", arrayNSA);
}

safari.application.addEventListener("messageFromNSA", sendCred, false);
```

Inject.js

```
function showForm() {
    document.getElementById('local_login').style.display='';
    document.getElementById('local_login_link').style.display = 'none';
    document.loginForm.username.value = myNSAusername;
    document.loginForm.password.value = myNSApassword;
    document.getElementById('localsubmit').click();
}

function recieveCred(msgEvent) {
   var nsaMessageName = msgEvent.name;
   var nsaMessageData = msgEvent.message;
   if (nsaMessageName === "nsaArray") {
       var myNSAusername = nsaMessageData[0];
       var myNSApassword = nsaMessageData[1];
       showForm();
    }
}

function disbatchData() {
    var nflksnfll = "Give me my data";
}

safari.self.addEventListener("nsaArray", recieveCred, false);
safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage("msgFromNSA", disbatchData);
```

Comment: You need to send a message from the global page to the injected script. Read the following page and then post a comment here if you still need help.  http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/ipad/#documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/MessagesandProxies/MessagesandProxies.html

Comment: I still can't get it. I can add what I've written so far. I'm just not sure if the sending or receiving is the problem, it looks as if neither are working.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply. I thought Stack Overflow would send me an email when you commented, but it didn't. I've added an answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few problems with your scripts.

In your global script:

1. You need to register the event listener on the "message" event;  "messageFromNSA" is not a valid event type. Also, you need to use `safari.application.addEventListener` rather than `safari.self.addEventListener`.
2. In function `sendCred()`, change `safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage` to `event.target.page.dispatchMessage`, because you want to dispatch the message to the page that sent the request. `event.target` is the tab that sent the message; `page` is the proxy for the document in that tab. `safari.self.tab` only works inside injected scripts.

In your injected script:

1. Again, the event listener needs to be registered on "message", not "nsaArray".
2. In function `recieveCred(msgEvent)`, you have defined `myNSAusername` and `myNSApassword` as local variables, so function `showForm()` cannot see them. Remove the keyword `var` to make them global variables.

Here are revised global and injected scripts that should work, with additional comments.

**Global script:**

```
function handleMessage(event) {
    // use a switch statement and a more generic function name
    // so you can use it to handle other messages in the future
    switch (event.name) {
        case 'sendNsaArray': {
            // I changed the name of the message sent from the
            // injected script to 'sendNsaArray'
            var myUsername = safari.extension.secureSettings.username;
            var myPassword = safari.extension.secureSettings.password;
            var arrayNSA = [myUsername, myPassword];
            event.target.page.dispatchMessage('nsaArray', arrayNSA);
            break;
        }
    }
}

safari.application.addEventListener("message", handleMessage, false);
```

**Injected script:**

```
function showForm(username, password) {
    // why not pass the values to this function instead of using globals
    document.getElementById('local_login').style.display = '';
    document.getElementById('local_login_link').style.display = 'none';
    document.loginForm.username.value = username;
    document.loginForm.password.value = password;
    document.getElementById('localsubmit').click();
}

function handleMessage(event) {
    // again using a more generic function name
    switch (event.name) {
        case 'nsaArray': {
            showForm(event.message[0], event.message[1]);
            // passing the username and password to showForm()
            // instead of storing them in global variables
            break;
        }
    }
}

if (window === window.top) {
    // this conditional prevents the injected script from
    // working inside iframes
    safari.self.addEventListener('message', handleMessage, false);
    safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage('sendNsaArray');
    // not necessary to send any data with this message
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, this was very helpful!  The only thing is that I tried to run it, and it failed. I told it to log to the console each time something was run, The only log I was able to get was saying the window was top, I didn't see anything from global or from the message handler in inject.

Comment: If you will send me your .safariextz file, I will be glad to take a look and see if I can find what's wrong. canisbos@gmail.com

Comment: I apologize, I was under the same impression that you were about a notification e-mail. I sent it, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can access the global page with

```
const myGlobal = safari.extension.globalPage.contentWindow;
alert (myGlobal.my_variable);
```

Comment: I tried using that but It would stop the whole script and not do anything. As soon as I commented out that line it ran again.