# Safari Extension Send Message to Injected Script

Tags: javascript, safari, safari-extension

I am designing a safari application and have found that I need to be able to send data from the global page to an injected script and, after reading the Apple documentation, discovered that I will need to use messages.

Originally, I tried to write messages to do what I wanted and that failed. Then, I simplified the code to just send a basic message and that failed as well. After narrowing it down to what I believe the error to be, here is the code I tried:

Global.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    // Set up the Listener
    safari.application.addEventListener("command", performCommand, false);

    // Function to perform when event is received
    function performCommand(event) {
        // Make sure event comes from the button
        if (event.command == "parseGrades") {
            alert('made it');
            safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.page.dispatchMessage("execute", "engage");
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Inject.js:

```
safari.self.addEventListener("message", handleMessage, false);
function handleMessage(msgEvent) {
    alert('message received');
}
```

When I run the extension, I get a single alert which says "made it" but I never get the alert which says "message received" (which is what I am trying to get).

In terms of the extension settings themselves, I have website access set to all and to include secure pages and I have global.html set as the global page and Inject.js set as an end script.

I also tried Inject.js set as a start script but that had the same effect as setting it as an end script so I changed it back to being an end script.

I cross-referenced with the following:

1. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/MessagesandProxies/MessagesandProxies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH14-SW1 - according to these docs, it should work
2. [Safari Extension - Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994266/safari-extension-message)
3. [Safari extension messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739047/safari-extension-messaging)
4. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500614/safari-extension-accessing-variable (deleted)
5. etc…

Based on these sources, it seems to me that it should work but I am obviously wrong :).

Comment: Everything you have looks fine to me. If you open the Web Inspector and look under Resources, is your injected script in the "Extension Scripts" folder? In the past I have found that during development some sort of caching occasionally prevents injected scripts loading until Safari has been restarted.

Comment: @MattSwain Thank you so much! It was not in the extension scripts folder and when I restarted Safari, everything worked and it appeared in the extension scripts folder upon inspection. You just saved me hours of headache :)

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be because Safari caches the extension scripts for the page, which prevents the message from being received.

This is the error:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.page.dispatchMessage)
```

It presumably means that `safari.application.activeBrowserWindow` doesn't exist, because the injected script hasn't actually been injected, so there's nothing to send the message to.

Restarting Safari seemed to do the trick.

Comment: This is almost helpful :) --is there any way to disable the cacheing? Any documentation of this behavior or way to handle it? Killing me here...

Comment: @ericpeters0n I haven't been able to find anything about it anywhere; the caching is an assumption based on the behavior I've seen from it.

Comment: Yup, I see this behavior as well. One of a number of undocumented quirks in Safari's Browser Extension architecture. ;)